# Gradle Build Failed With ml-gradle plugin install

Tags: gradle, ml-gradle

I just installed Gradle via homebrew. Version 7.0. I ran a hello world task with no error. Then I followed the instructions for installing ml-gradle (https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle). I get Build Failed with:

> What went wrong:
> Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':mlNewProject' (type 'NewProjectTask').
>
> - Type 'NewProjectTask' property 'adminManager' is missing an input or output annotation.
>
>   Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

Not sure where to start. Any ideas?

OSX
gradle -version

---

### Gradle 7.0

Build time:   2021-04-09 22:27:31 UTC
Revision:     d5661e3f0e07a8caff705f1badf79fb5df8022c4

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          15.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 15.0.2+7)
OS:           Mac OS X 11.2.3 x86_64

java -version
openjdk version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you.  I had a similar issue using gradle 7.1.  I installed version 6.8 and it is working fine.